# How is a row assigned to a region and region server in Hbase?

Tags: hbase

I am not able to understand how, or who ( which component ) is responsible for assigning a hbase row to a region or region server? In other db systems for example, the client code hashes the key and asks "some" master node where to place the module of the calculated hash. For example, in cassandra each node has metadata about the key ranges every node is supposed to store and the "coordinator" node simply forwards it to that node

Answer (score 1):

Each HBase region defined by range of keys(`[startRow, endRow)`) which can be stored in it. Each region assigned to some RegionServer which handle requests to it.
HBase client scans `meta` table which contains information about regions and where it located(on which RegionServer). On each request, client determine to which RegionServer it should send this request.

Comment: So the client does a range check for the input partition key against the hbase meta table?

Comment: It make scan and cache all regions locations of table. During next request, it use locally cached knowledge to find appropriate RegionServer.